# How to serialize a model using different field names?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model with an id and a label:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    label = models.TextField()
```

And I want to serialize the label and id, so I have a serializer like this:

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ('id', 'label')
```

This gives me a serialization like `{"id": 61, "label": "Super Widget"}`. However, I need to give the serialization different labels (e.g. `{"widget_id": 61, "widget_name": "Super Widget"}`) without changing the model since it's used in different places. Is there a way to tell the serializer to serialize a field using a different label?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can’t achieve that with "serializers.ModelSerializer" but you can achieve it with "serializers.Serializer".

Try something like this:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label="widget_id")
    label = serializers.CharField(label="widget_name")
```

For more information: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializer-fields
And for some examples: http://hackersome.com/p/jezdez/django-serializers

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work in Django 3.0.7. I get `This field is required`.